# redshift nulling columns when joining another table

Tags: left-join, amazon-redshift

table_1 has 35 columns, table_2 has 20 columns

query is:

```
select table1.*,
  table2.f1,
  ...
  table2.f20
FROM public.table_1 as table1
    left join public.table_2 as table2
    on table1.id = table2.id 
        and table1.arrival_time::date <= table2.end_date::date
        and table2.activity_date < table2.end_date
;
```

this works I expect 469 rows to be returned and that's what I get. However several fields from table_1 get displayed as null instead of the values in the table.

These fields are NOT part of the join.

Due to IP concerns I can't provide the full details of the tables, each field in table_1 and table_2 are varchar (don't ask me why a timestamp is stored as a varchar - its a long story that I have no control over)

This query WORKS in RDS PostgreSQL!

Any ideas why it has a problem in redshift?

Comment: Because `table1` appears on the leftmost side of the join, it isn't possible that the join itself would be causing `NULL` values to appear for any column from `table1`.  Something else is going on here.

Comment: You need to check that table1 doesn't have NULLs in the columns in questions on Redshift.  I expect that there was a data load issue moving the data from RDS (or whatever is source) to Redshift.

Comment: Bill: select * from table_1 shows values in the fields!
Tim: I know - right, I'm hoping someone else has seen the redshift weirdness before and can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll be very confused.
table_1 is data from two sources joined together - I didn't even think to look at the sources. Turns out the linked source had no data for one value.

Just goes to show that when looking at just a piece of the data you need to look HARD at all the data.

Now I'm off to find a better source for the missing data.

Thanks for your time!
James